# Is there a way to configure the serialization response in a minimal C# API?

Tags: c#, minimal-apis

I tried using the following line

```
builder.Services.Configure<JsonSerializerOptions>(options => options.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter()));
```

to configure that the enums are converted to string when returning

```
return Results.Ok(new SummarizationResult(SummarizationStatus.InProcess));
```

being the enum

```
public enum SummarizationStatus
{
    Ok,
    Failed,
    InProcess
}
```

But that keeps returning the enum as a number 2

```
{
    "status": 2,
    "message": null,
    "summary": null
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add the converter to the `JsonOptions`

`builder.Services.Configure<JsonOptions>`